# Nlog Delete SQLite longer than X days

Tags: nlog

xsi:type="File" has  maxArchiveFiles="5" archiveEvery="Day" properties. Is that possibble to delete db content older than X days?

xsi:type="Database" has rules for that purpose?

My sample Nlog.config;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd NLog.xsd"
      autoReload="true"
      throwExceptions="false"
      throwConfigExceptions="true"      
      internalLogLevel="Off" internalLogFile="c:\temp\nlog-internal.log">


  <targets>
    <!--target name="logfile" xsi:type="File" fileName="file.txt" /!-->

    <target xsi:type="Database"
            name="db"
            dbProvider="System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection, System.Data.SQLite"
            connectionString="Data Source=log.db3;"
            commandType="Text"
            commandText="INSERT into Log(Timestamp, Loglevel, Callsite, Message) values(@Timestamp, @Loglevel, @Callsite, @Message)"            
            >

      <parameter name="@Timestamp" layout="${longdate}"/>
      <parameter name="@Loglevel" layout="${level:uppercase=true}"/>
      <parameter name="@Callsite" layout="${callsite:filename=true}"/>
      <parameter name="@Message" layout="${message}"/>
    </target>
      <target name="colouredConsole" xsi:type="ColoredConsole" useDefaultRowHighlightingRules="false" layout="${longdate}|${pad:padding=5:inner=${level:uppercase=true}}|${message}">
      <highlight-row condition="level == LogLevel.Debug" foregroundColor="DarkGray" />
      <highlight-row condition="level == LogLevel.Info" foregroundColor="Gray" />
      <highlight-row condition="level == LogLevel.Warn" foregroundColor="Yellow" />
      <highlight-row condition="level == LogLevel.Error" foregroundColor="Red" />
      <highlight-row condition="level == LogLevel.Fatal" foregroundColor="Red" backgroundColor="White" />
    </target>
    
  </targets>

  <rules>
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Info" maxlevel="Info" writeTo="colouredConsole" />
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Error" maxlevel="Error" writeTo="colouredConsole" />
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Debug" maxlevel="Debug" writeTo="colouredConsole" />
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Debug" maxlevel="Debug" writeTo="db" />
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Error" maxlevel="Error" writeTo="db" />
  </rules>
</nlog>
```

How to delete sqlite db content older than 7 days?

Answer (score 0):

Some people suggests  EnsureDb(); it works but I want to ask any possibility to set from xsi:type="Database" parameters?

```
private static void EnsureDb()
            {
                if (File.Exists("log.db3"))
                {
              
                    
                    using (SQLiteConnection connection = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=log.db3"))
                    using (SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(
                        "DELETE FROM Log WHERE Timestamp <= datetime('now', '-7 day');",
                        connection))
                    {
                        connection.Open();
                        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
    
                    return;
                }
                using (SQLiteConnection connection = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=log.db3"))
                using (SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(
                    "CREATE TABLE Log (Timestamp TEXT, Loglevel TEXT, Callsite TEXT, Message TEXT)",
                    connection))
                {
                    connection.Open();
                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }
```

Comment: I guess you can make a [pull-request](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/pulls) for the NLog-project to add support for periodic-command-text. That can be triggered at startup, or by specified frequency (hourly/daily/weekly/weekday/etc.)

Comment: Thank you for your help, but I could not manage to find solution can you give example for the usage?